# Stored Procedure if else

Tags: mysql, if-statement, stored-procedures

I dont know why when i call this procedure " CALL sp_buy_products ('Longan', 2); " I keep getting the out of stock message while the stock for Longan is 67. Please help me. Thank you.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_buy_products (IN p_product_name VARCHAR(50), IN p_quantity INT)

BEGIN
    DECLARE p_product_name VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE  p_quantity INT;
    DECLARE  v_count INT;

    SELECT count(1)
    INTO v_count
    FROM products
    WHERE p_quantity <= quantity_in_stock AND name = p_product_name;
    
    IF v_count > 0 THEN
    UPDATE products SET quantity_in_stock = (quantity_in_stock - p_quantity)
    WHERE name = p_product_name;
    SELECT 'Product sold!';
    
    ELSE 
    SELECT 'Sorry! Out of stock!';
    END IF;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You shouldn't declare local variables that are the same as the parameters. That's shadowing the parameters. So get rid of the declarations of `p_product_name` and `p_quantity`.

Comment: hi, so i should change the name of the parameters?

Comment: No. Just get rid of the variable declarations, they're not needed. Putting them in the parameter list declares them.

Comment: I am using mysql to write that query. I thought i had to declare them but i didnt have to?

Comment: No! They're declared by `(IN p_product_name VARCHAR(50), IN p_quantity INT)`

Comment: Why would you need to declare the type twice?

Comment: because mysql tutorial posted that on their website. I remove them but still got the wrong message.

Comment: I can't see any other problem with your procedure.

Comment: It works for me when I remove the unneeded declarations: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uS74ML6W2rZd7CkkhnDdt/0

Comment: Could you please provide us with the table structure of `products`?  And it would nice to have the row data of Longan as well.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the local declarations of the parameter variables. The parameter list declares them automatically.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_buy_products (IN p_product_name VARCHAR(50), IN p_quantity INT)

BEGIN
    DECLARE  v_count INT;

    SELECT count(1)
    INTO v_count
    FROM products
    WHERE p_quantity <= quantity_in_stock AND name = p_product_name;
    
    IF v_count > 0 THEN
        UPDATE products SET quantity_in_stock = (quantity_in_stock - p_quantity)
        WHERE name = p_product_name;
        SELECT 'Product sold!';
    ELSE 
        SELECT 'Sorry! Out of stock!';
    END IF;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uS74ML6W2rZd7CkkhnDdt/0)

Comment: db-fiddle tested as intended. I wonder if something went amiss when the OP ran the `SELECT count(1) INTO v_count` statement, which might always return a value <= 0 in his case.

Comment: @blabla_bingo I can't count the number of times I've described a simple fix in a comment, they say it doesn't work, I post the code with that fix, they say it worked. They don't always make the fix correctly.

Comment: One thing bothers me. The OP uses `SELECT count(1)` to count the first column. What if that column allows null value and the line which passes the if condition check  happens to have a null for its first column . e.g `create table products(ISO_no varchar(20) default null, name VARCHAR(50), quantity_in_stock INT);` ,`INSERT INTO products (name,quantity_in_stock) VALUES ('Longan', 67);` This will fail the if condition check.

Comment: @blabla_bingo That doesn't count column 1. It counts the literal 1, which is never null, so it's equivalent to `COUNT(*)`

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thank you for your correction. The test stands true. `create table test(id int,num int);` .  `insert test values(1,3),(5,7),(null,5)` , `select count(id) from test; -- result 2` , `select count(1) from test; -- result 3` .